# align list items content at the same level

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

What this the best way to accomplish the following? using tabular ?

i dont want to use `\hfill` and pushing them to the end of the line.

```
• list-item           i want this
• longggg-item        and this to be aligned
• another-item        at the same level auto
```

in a more general way

```
• some text                  i want this                  same here
• another text               and this to be at the        same here
• not the same length        same level after let say     seconde level here
```

Comment: I guess that the `tabto` package is what you're looking for.

Comment: i will see btw \quad isnt helping in case. maybe a trick with minipage i never used it.

Comment: thank you both tabular and tabto works, i am sure in some cases one is better than the other so i will keep note of both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mybullet{{\tiny\raise0.5ex\hbox{\textbullet}\ }} % custom-size "bullet"
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{\mybullet}ll}
list-item & i want this\\
longgg-item & and this to be aligned\\
another-item & at the same level auto\\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{\mybullet}lll}
some text & i want this & same here\\
some other text & and this to be at the & same here\\
not the same length & same level after let say & seconde level here\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Why is the screenshot 'blurred'?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - This is a rather long-standing issue with the way my system creates and/or uploads screenshots to this site. Confusingly, the screenshots look blurred in some web browsers but not in others. (FWIW, they never look blurred on my system; I use FireFox to view the webpages, and I use Acrobat to create the png files that are uploaded.) Over the years, several helpful people have tried valiantly tried to help me figure out how to get rid of the occasional blurriness, but alas without success. At least they helped me get rid of the soft-pink background color! :-)

Comment: I am using FireFoX 43.03 on Linux, the Acrobat Reader (the latest version 9.4 made for Linux :-( ), but I copy the screenshots with gimp and let that software create the `.png` or `.jpg` files.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Thanks. I think I need to make a renewed effort to figure out how to create screenshots that are less blurry on everybody's screens. What's been frustrating me is that screenshots actually never look blurry on my own system (a MacBookPro with a 13-inch "retina display" screen). Hence, it's not easy for me to figure out what's really going on. :-(